# Как через jquery в textarea вставить тег

Tags: jquery

Не могу в текст. область вставить скрипт:

```
$('textarea').val('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site"></script>');
```

Если < установить как &lt; то и в текстарее тоже будет &lt;

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример на хешкоде отработал.
[image]